# Reading specific data

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a data file with makes and models of vehicles and their engine size. The data file (txt file) looks like this (I have only added a few examples):

```
Vauxhall
Astra
1.2
Vauxhall
Corsa
1.4
VW
Polo
2.0
BMW
3Series
3.0
```

What I want to do is to extract only specific data from that file. So for example have an input statement:

```
Search = input("Please select the Make of vehicle?")
```

I want the program to read the file and only select the make, model and engine size relevant to the criteria. I know how to read data from files, however I need help with the above issue.

Comment: Is transforming the text file in a small database an option ? Then extracting specific data is done with really simple queries.   But if the text file is not too big, you could always store the data in nested lists `[ [make,model,engine], [make, model, engine], ...]` and then iterate through the list to find specific data.

Answer (score 1):

If database isn't an option then the approach suggested by tmoreau will work though it won't be as efficient as DB based approach. I will develop further on that approach:

Read your input file line by line and store it in list of lists with each internal list containing 3 items: make,model,engine

```
    list_of_list = []
    current_list = []
    index = 0
    in_file = open(input_file,'r')
    line = in_file.readline()
    while(line):
     while index < 3:
            current_list.append(line)
            index = index + 1
            line = in_file.readline()
        index = 0
        list_of_list.append(current_list)
        current_list = []
```

This should create a list of lists. Now based on what user query is; you can check the index of internal lists: for example if user query is engine then check 2nd element of each nested list. So first step is figuring out what is the user asking about. Once you are done with that; you can proceed like the following:
suppose the user wants to query based on model (index 1 in nested list) and wants to query about say corsa.
you should have variables like these

```
    index_reqd = 1 (translate user input to index) 
    var = corsa
```

```
    for nest_list in list_of_list:
         if net_list[index_reqd] == var:
             print net_list
```